# How to distinguish two usb printers in an android device

Tags: android, printing, usb

There are two printers plugged into an android board by usb ports. I was trying to print doc from the android device. when the first printer plug in, there will be a path "dev/usb/lp0" show up. and the second one will be "dev/usb/lp1". but the problem is i don't know which usb port is lp0, which port is lp1. Then i can't print things from the specific printer.

I've googled the question , and i found that we can change the lp0 to serial number in linux, (Assign fixed path to printer (/dev/usb/lp0)) but can we do that in android?

Thanks.